# Windows 10 search bar and edge not working?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, search, cortana

All my windows 10 features like search , cortona and edge stopped worked.I searched for different solutions and tried different codes and executed in the elevated powershell but no use.

Any solutions?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: [edit] and tell us what you have actually tried.

Comment: configure your Windows to generate crash dumps: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57 Zip the dmp files and share them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suggest that you use the "refresh PC" option. All your files will be kept on the disk but any program will get deleted.

1. Write down the programs you have
2. Get a Windows 10 Install CD. It has special features for recovery
3. Language Options and then in the corner "Repair your computer"
4. Troubleshoot > Reset this PC

Here's more information

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options